# yii2 redirect based on access role to change password page

Tags: php, redirect, yii2, rbac

I have simple role-based access set up in my Yii2 application that works like this:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'ruleConfig' => [
                   'class' => AccessRule::className(),
               ],
               'only' => ['logout', 'contact', 'change-password'],
               'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['login'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['?'],
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['logout', 'contact', 'change-password'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => [
                        User::ROLE_USER,
                        User::ROLE_ADMIN
                    ],
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['logout', 'change-password'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => [
                        User::ROLE_NEW_USER
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'logout' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

When users are not logged in, attempting to access the logout, contact, or change-password pages will redirect to the login page. I would also like to configure this so that users with role ROLE_NEW_USER are always redirected to the change-password page until their status changes (the status is updated in the database when the password is changed).

Is it possible to do this with denyCallback, or is there a way to use the redirect to the login page to redirect to other pages?

Answer (score 0):

As in documentation:

Access rules support many options. **You may also extend [yii\filters\AccessRule](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-accessrule.html) to create your own customized access rule classes**.

This allows you create a custom rule that checks if user has´n change password yet and redirect wherever you want

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after some mucking about, I managed to get it working with the beforeAction() function:

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{
        if (Url::current() != Url::toRoute('site/change-password') 
            && isset(Yii::$app->user->getIdentity()->role) 
            && Yii::$app->user->getIdentity()->role == User::ROLE_NEW_USER) {
            return Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect(Url::toRoute('site/change-password'));
        }

        if (!parent::beforeAction($action)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true; 
}
```

Make sure you include Url::current() != Url::toRoute('site/change-password') or you end up in a redirect loop.